# Distance between two parallel planes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Given the normals ($n_1$ and $n_2$) of two parallel planes is it possible to  calculate the distance between these two planes. if so, how?

Am coding some app and the normals are the only thing I have got.

Comment: If they are parallel, $n_1=\pm n_2$

Comment: You will need the coordinates of a point in each plane and a normal to compute the distance

Answer (score 4):

The normal vectors alone provide no information on the distance between the planes.
$d=\left|\left(\vec{x}_{1}-\vec{x}_{2}\right) \cdot \hat n \right|$

Comment: If you have the normal vectors plus a point which lies on the plane for each plane, you can then compute the distance.

Comment: Ok let me try it.